# Finding the CORRECT way to solve for Impulse in 2D Collisions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

Firstly, my apologies as I forgot this website does not allow Check My Work type of discussions. Thank you to those who answered the reasonings by the way,

Basically, my question was as follows:

In a 2D collision, is there a reason why you cannot find the resultant velocities of an object before and after a collision and use that to find impulse? Why do you have to find each impulse component first using a change in velocity for x and y) before you solve using Pythagorean theorem?

Comment: You've actually done what you're saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that impulse is defined as $$\vec{J} = \vec{P}_f - \vec{P}_i$$ If you just want the magnitude, you can consider the magnitude of both sides of the equation above
$$|\vec{J}| = |\vec{P}_f - \vec{P}_i|$$
For any two vectors in general
$$| \vec{P}_f - \vec{P}_i| \neq | \vec{P}_f| - | \vec{P}_i |$$ A good example to consider is two opposite pointing vectors, say $\vec{A} = 4 \hat{i}$ and $\vec{B} = -4\hat{i}$. Here, $\vec{A} - \vec{B} = 8\hat{i}$. So, $| \vec{A} - \vec{B}| =8$ while $| \vec{A}| - | \vec{B}|=0$. Since you want the magnitude of the impulse, you must find the vector $\vec{P}_f - \vec{P}_i$ first and then find its magnitude with Pythagoras and not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it was an order of operations type issue.